# Reshape dataset using two columns' values and with missing data

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I want to reshape my dataset that has missing data from long to wide using two columns' values as the new dataset's columns. Here is an example:

```
ID  Survey  Question  Response
1        1         1         1
1        1         2         2
1        2         1         3
1        2         2         
1        2         3         4
1        3         1         3
1        3         2         4
2        1         1         2
2        1         2         
2        2         1         6
2        2         2         2
2        2         3         3
2        3         1         
2        3         2         5
```

I want it to look like this

```
ID Survey1.Q1 Survey1.Q2 Survey2.Q1 Survey2.Q2 Survey2.Q3 Survey3.Q1 Survey3.Q1
1           1          2          3                     4          3          4
2           2                     6          2          3                     5
```

Comment: Can you add a dput() of your example data? Anything you've already tried? Why did it not work? And is there a specific reason you need this format? It's not very 'tidy data'.

Comment: Try `library(dcast); dcast(df1, ID~Survey+Question, value.var='Response')`  I guess for this example, I am getting the expected as you showed.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your help from before! I am still stuck on this problem in that instead of all the columns are of numeric type, Survey and Question are factors and Response is numeric.

Comment: Then add a dput of your data...

Comment: @heroka the dataset's dim is 31k * 4

Comment: Already been solved, but for the future: Here's how to create a [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You could do dput(head(data)) for example.

Comment: @akrun [this is of course unprovable] I had already written the syntax when you commented. dcast-syntax can be very uniform. Got distracted with something, added formatting and posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you may choose to format your data while casting (thanks @Pierre)

```
res <- dcast(ID~paste0("Survey",Survey)+paste0("Q",Question),
    value.var="Response",data=dat)
```

Answer (score 2):

with `reshape()` from `{stats}`:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'ID  Survey  Question  Response
1        1         1         1
1        1         2         2
1        2         1         3
1        2         2         NA
1        2         3         4
1        3         1         3
1        3         2         4
2        1         1         2
2        1         2         NA
2        2         1         6
2        2         2         2
2        2         3         3
2        3         1         NA
2        3         2         5')
d$t <- 10*d$Survey+d$Question
reshape(d[,-(2:3)], dir="wide", timevar="t", idvar="ID")
```